# Magit: display notes in logs

Tags: magit

I would like to know, is it possible to write the note added to a commit in the log buffer? That way I don't need to open the commit to read the notes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not supported no and I don't intend to implement it anytime soon.

Comment: Ok thank you! Is there any function easy to configure to allow some custom display in the log buffer?